# Error with Selector in TestCafe - method .find()

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I'm struggling to define a selector in TestCafe with the ".find" method,I need to click that link "Start a claim" as per image below. [image]

I'm using the id element and using the ".find" to go to the link. It seems Testcafe is not happy with that selector, it throws error as "undefined" very often...

```
await t.(Selector('#policySummaryDetails_M0014157733').find('#claimLink_0'))
```

Answer (score 3):

> `await t.(Selector('#policySummaryDetails_M0014157733').find('#claimLink_0'))`

You forgot to call the `click` method of `t`. If you wish to click that link you need to rewrite your code as follows:

```
await t.click(Selector('#policySummaryDetails_M0014157733').find('#claimLink_0'))
```